# Input mix for Keras: Timeseries and Features

Tags: input, keras, time-series

I have several time series Features (ECG, HRV and breathing) and separate features made from those time series (e.g. SDNN, RMSSD,...).

I follow Francois Chollet with the naming. For a 3D timeseries input tensor they use [samples,timestep,features]

The time series have 15000 values(samples) per timestep [[15000x1],[15000x1],...] while the separate features have 1 value (sample) per timestep.Those extra features  with length [1] are different for each timestep. [[0.3],[0.35],[0.34],...].

```
                     ECG,      HRV,   F1,   F2,  ...
-------------------------------------------------------------
Sequence 1 |
    Step 1 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 
    Step 2 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 
    Step 3 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 

Sequence 2 |
    Step 1 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 
    Step 2 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 
    Step 3 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...]
```

How would you best approach to learn on all those inputs with Keras?

1. Just zero pad the separate features from 1 to 15000 and add them to the time series
2. Pad the separate features with themselves (using the one value repeatedly)
3. As the data is normalized between 0 and 1, using a value way outside of that range of the extra features to pad. E.g. 1000
4. Have only the time series as 3D tensor input and the separate features as an additional input (as extra layers)  and merge them into the learner (multi-input)

Extra question. How does zero padding influence the learner due to the "false" additional information? Especially for the 1 to 15000 part for the separate feature from above. Another example: the HRV and breathing signals are shorter than the ECG due to different sample frequency. Here I would use rather an interpolation instead of zero padding. Would you agree, or does zero padding not influence the learner?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please rewrite your description? I can't understand if you have 15000 steps or 15000 values per step. Also, it's ambiguous whether you have just a single unique feature or a varying feature per step.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assumption 1

Due to the ambiguity, I'm assuming this (please comment if not and I'll change it)

- I'm calling ECG, HRV, etc. **features** that vary per step
- Your feature with the highest frequency has 15000 steps, while the other features have less steps
- You have a separate feature that is not sequential and has no steps. (I'll call it the **separate feature** in this answer)

**Extra question:**

Yes! Interpolate the less frequent features and make an input tensor like:

- `(numberOfSequences_maybePatient, 15000 steps, features_ECG_HRV_etc)`

You need to keep a correlation between the features on **when** they happen, and this is made by synchronizing the steps.

**Will zero padding influence the results?**

Yes it will, unless you use "masking" (a masking layer). But this will only make sense for handling **samples** (different sequence or patients) with different lengths, not **features** with different length/sample rate.

Example, the following case would work well with zero padding and masking:

- sequence 1: length 100 (all features included, ECG, HRV, etc.)
- sequence 2: length 200 (all features included, ECG, HRV, etc.)

**How to deal with the `separate feature`?**

There are a number of possible ways. One of the most simple ones, and probably very effective, is to make it a constant sequence with all the 15000 steps. This approach does not require thinking about how the feature relates to the rest of the data, and leaves the task to the model

Suppose the separate feature value is 2 for the first sequence and 4 for the second sequence, make then this data array:

```
                          ECG, HRV, separate
--------------------------------------------------------
             |   [
sequence 1:  |      [
step 1       |            [ecg1, hrv1, 2],
step 2       |            [ecg2, hrv2, 2],
step 3       |            [ecg3, hrv3, 2]
             |      ]
             |
sequence 2:  |      [
step 1       |            [ecg4, hrv4, 4],
step 2       |            [ecg5, hrv5, 4],
step 3       |            [ecg6, hrv6, 4]
             |      ]
             |   ]
```

You can also input is as an additional input in the model:

```
regularSequences = Input((15000,features))
separateFeature = Input((1,)) #assuming 1 value per sequence
```

And then you decide if you want to sum it somewhere, multiply it somewhere, etc. This approach might be more effective than the other if you have an idea of what this feature means and how it relates to the rest of the data to select the best operations and where.

### Assumption 2

Taking this description from your updated answer:

```
                     ECG,      HRV,   F1,   F2,  ...
-------------------------------------------------------------
Sequence 1 |
    Step 1 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 
    Step 2 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 
    Step 3 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 

Sequence 2 |
    Step 1 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 
    Step 2 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...] 
    Step 3 |     [[15000x1],[1000x1],[1x1],[1x1],...]
```

Then:

- You have 15000 features for a single time step in the ECG. (Are you sure this is not a sequence of 15000 steps?)
- You have 1000 features for a single time step in HRV. (Are you sure this is not a sequence of 1000 steps?)
- You have several other individual features per time step.

Well, organizing this data is quite easy (but mind the questions I asked above), just pack all features together in each time step:

The shape of your input data will be: `(sequences, steps, 16002)`

```
                     ECG,      HRV,   F1,   F2,  ...
-------------------------------------------------------------
              [
Sequence 1 |    [
    Step 1 |     [ecg1,ecg2,...,ecg15000,hrv1,hrv2,...hrv1000,F1,F2,...]
    Step 2 |     [ecg1,ecg2,...,ecg15000,hrv1,hrv2,...hrv1000,F1,F2,...]
    Step 3 |     [ecg1,ecg2,...,ecg15000,hrv1,hrv2,...hrv1000,F1,F2,...]
                ]
Sequence 2 |    [
    Step 1 |     [ecg1,ecg2,...,ecg15000,hrv1,hrv2,...hrv1000,F1,F2,...]
    Step 2 |     [ecg1,ecg2,...,ecg15000,hrv1,hrv2,...hrv1000,F1,F2,...]
    Step 3 |     [ecg1,ecg2,...,ecg15000,hrv1,hrv2,...hrv1000,F1,F2,...]
                ]
```

Comment: Dear Daniel, thanks a lot for your elaborate answer. Padding to keep the synch makes a lot of sense. I just thought (better hoped), that if I pad a feature with one value per step, to e.g. 15000 per step, the learner will notice, that for the extra feature only the first value of the step is important.

Comment: #2 Another question about your suggestion of the sequences. My problem is that the ECG1 is 15000 values for sequence1/step1 and the extra feature 2. Therefore, I cannot create this tensor as input. Or did I misinterpreted something? Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks for the addition. To clarify: Each timestep (30s) has 15000 Samples. As the ECG has a sample frequency of 500Hz (30s*500Hz=15000samples). So I think you missinterpreted my samples for features. I think our misunderstanding is, that I call your sequence samples (I followed Francois Chollet on this one). The ECG as a whole dataseries is a feature. Same for HRV etc.  ...

Comment: ... If I look at the documentation on time series it says that the 3D tensor as to be in the format: [samples, timestep, features]. If  I would just merge all features, it seems to me that the tensor would lose its correct form if I just merge all features. Do I oversee soemthing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok, you're using the word "samples" in a signal way (for instance, sample rate = 500hz), while I'm using it in a keras way (samples are individual and unrelated sequences - Sequence 1 is a sample, Sequence 2 is another sample). In keras, you actually have 15000 time steps. Can you please explain the role of the 30s?

Comment: You should come back to **Assumption 1**, but what you're calling "step" is probably what I'm calling "individual sequence or sample". Interpolate the HRV to 15000 steps, and add your features as a constant value to all 15000 steps.

Comment: I think, we mean the same :-) The 30s are the time steps. So I have a signal of a total length of e.g. 10min. I also have annotations (y-values) for every 30s. Therefore, I use a timestep of 30s (in total 20 steps 30s*20=10min). As the ECG has a 500Hz sample frequency, I get 15000 samples per timestep. I hope that cleared it a bit.

Comment: So you have one sequence with 300.000 time steps. Copy constant values of F1, F2, etc, into this array and change the constant value each 15.000 steps.